# how to get images for ipad custom keyboard

Tags: ios4, uikeyboard

Does anyone know how to get the button images and gradients for a custom ipad keyboard? I would like these buttons to look like the system keyboard buttons, but with different text on them. I have the background gradient values, and I can create a CGGradient(and subsequently UIImage) to get a background. The problem is when I try to set the background of a UIButton as a UIImage, i end up getting a square button. I thought that the image will fill into the rounded rect portion of a rounded rect button, but this is not the case.

Does anyone know how to do these buttons? I guess I could get a png for each button, but that just seems silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My UX Designer said that they appear to be Photoshopped images, so he was going to create them for me.  Apple does not typically make their graphics accessible except when defined in an non-mutable or opaque way (i.e., UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel).